# Formatting objects in chai.expect errors

Tags: mocha.js, chai

When test fails, where I'm comparing two objects using `expect(x).to.deep.equal(y)`, I'd like to see the actual values in my browser test report. Instead, I see something like this:

```
AssertionError: expected { Object (x, y, ...) } to deeply equal { Object (x, y, ...) }
```

So it doesn't really show anything useful.

Is there a way to customize how chai.js formats these objects?

Comment: I have a similar question posted. I have no solution, so commenting here: can someone rationalize why it would ever be useful to spit out things like prototype properties and functions on an object in a failed assertion? This is a huge part of why the output is typically too large and either gets truncated or (if setting zero truncating) is absurdly long and hard to read through. It would also be nice to have just an option to prefer using toString(), as I often will add such methods to my own objects/classes for development purposes or otherwise, which would be far more useful in test output

Comment: ... here's a link to the similar question @JasonBoyd mentions: [How can I get Chai to show actual and expected values using toString()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26980779/1684079).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can now configure the max length before an object gets truncated as per [the docs](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#config-truncatethreshold):

```
chai.config.truncateThreshold = 0; // disable truncating
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really. This is hardcoded into Chai.
The following function is their object formatter (source [here](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/blob/4b51ea75484eae9225a4330d267f5e231f208ed0/lib/chai/utils/objDisplay.js#L36)), which does exactly what you posted:

```
} else if (type === '[object Object]') {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj)
    , kstr = keys.length > 2
      ? keys.splice(0, 2).join(', ') + ', ...'
      : keys.join(', ');
  return '{ Object (' + kstr + ') }';
```