# How can I get Chai to show actual and expected values using toString()

Tags: chai

I recently switched from should.js to chai.js, as I discovered the former was causing snags in browser-based testing. The change didn't require any changes to my test suite, as the syntax is supported, but I see that the output of failing tests no longer shows me the actual and expected values in a useful way:

```
AssertionError: expected [ Array(9) ] to deeply equal [ Array(9) ]
```

I can get it to spit out a representation of these values by adding this line:

```
chai.config.truncateThreshold = 0;
```

However this results in every value being exhaustively output, including functions, and including prototype properties. Also pretty useless.

So is there some way I am missing to have chai behave like should.js, where actual/expected values are shown using their toString() method?

Comment: I can suggest to create issue in shouldjs repo, if you have problem with it. Should.js and chai.js use different objects inspections (how they printed)

Comment: @denbardadym are you saying chai reuses shouldjs code? Otherwise why would I report a chai issue to shouldjs repo? But yes, I suppose reporting the issue is next step. Still, I'm confused how this doesn't impact *everyone* who uses it, which is why I assumed I'm not figuring out how to do this. Why would anyone want test failures to report that [Object] does not match [Object]?

Comment: I mean that at the begginning (you call it some 'snaggs in browser')  you wrote that you have used should.js and that was ok, for some moment. So if you are ok with should.js why not just fix that issue? To be clear i am should.js maintainer, so i only can help you fix bugs in it.

Comment: Ah! Sorry, didn't understand. The issue I had with shouldjs was that it kept hanging Karma on second runs, no matter how I configured it. Switching to Chai resolved this long-standing issue, and at first seemed like a big win, as the test suites ran unmodified. I'll go file the issue with the project.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://www.chaijs.com/guide/styles/#configuration, chai now lets you disable truncating the length threshold for actual and expected values in assertion errors.

`chai.config.truncateThreshold = 0; // disable truncating`

Answer (score 0):

One way to get Chai (v1.10.0) to show actual and expected values using `.toString()` is to patch its `utils.objDisplay` at runtime.

The basic gist is:

```
chai.use(function(_chai,utils) {
  utils.objDisplay = function(obj) { return obj+''; };
});
```

However, it's slightly-more complicated to do in practice because of the way Chai instantiates duplicate (ie: `!==`) module references internally; in this case making it necessary to patch `utils.getMessage` also.

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate the overall patch along with a trivial example of custom formatting for `Array` objects: https://jsfiddle.net/humbletim/oc1tnqpy/

Comment: Thanks for this hack.
I put it into an NPM package :p
https://github.com/TeNNoX/chai-formatter-monkeypatch