# Array destructuring returned from promises not working as expected

Tags: mocha.js, es6-promise, chai, solidity

I am using [Mocha](https://mochajs.org/) and [Chai](https://www.chaijs.com/) for writing tests for a smart contract deployed on the development blockchain with truffle.

I have a contract named `Election` which contains two candidates.

The test code is as follows:

```
it("Checking the properties for candidates", () => {
    return Election.deployed().then((app) => {
      return [app.candidates(1), app];
    }).then(params => {
      const [candidate1, app] = params;
      assert.equal(candidate1.id, 0);
      return [app.candidates(1), app];
    }).then(params => {
      const [candidate2, app] = params;
      assert.equal(candidate2.id, 1);
    });
  });
```

The test cases pass when I am not using the array destructuring to return `app.candidates()` and an instance of the `app`. In that case I had to declare a global variable, assign it to `app` and use it in every scope. But I want to avoid defining a global variable. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703625/how-do-you-properly-return-multiple-values-from-a-promise) post on SO which suggests using ES6 destructuring.

But here I am getting `candidate1.id` and `candidate2.id` both as `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does `app.candidates(…)` return a promise? If so, you were forgetting a call to `Promise.all`. If not, you don't need to chain multiple `then` callbacks at all, just put everything in a single one!

Comment: Closely related: [How do I access previous promise results in a `.then()` chain?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28250680/1048572)

Comment: `app.candidates()` does not return promise. The link is helpful but I am already using `return` as shown in that link

Comment: If it doesn't return a promise, then what does it return? Does it return a candidate object with an `id` property?

Comment: Yes it returns an object with id property

Comment: Are you sure? Because then the code should work as is. Try logging the values before you put it in the array and and after destructuring.

Comment: Hey @Bergi. My bad. `app.candidates()` returns a promise. I was wrong assuming it otherwise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you returning from an `it`? It's not needed, they should only throw.

I strongly recommend avoiding this `.then` syntax and `npm i chai-as-promised --save-dev` then install it like this:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

// Must install Chai as Promised last - https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised/#node
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

// Disable object truncating - https://stackoverflow.com/a/23378037/1828637
chai.config.truncateThreshold = 0;

global.expect = chai.expect;
```

Then you would do:

```
it("Checking the properties for candidates", async () => {
    expect(Election.deployed()).to.eventually.satisfy(app => app.candidates(1).id === 0)
        and.satisfy(app => app.candidates(2).id === 1);
});
```

If `app.candidates` returns a promise, maybe can even do this, I'm not sure about async function to argument of `satisfy` though.

```
it("Checking the properties for candidates", async () => {
    expect(Election.deployed()).to.eventually.satisfy(async app => {
        await expect(app.candidates(1)).to.eventually.be.an('object').that.has.property('id', 0);
        await expect(app.candidates(2)).to.eventually.be.an('object').has.property('id', 1);
    });
});
```

Comment: "*Why are you returning from an it?*" - I'm pretty sure you need to return a promise as otherwise the test doesn't know when it is finished.

Comment: The code definitely looks cleaner without the `then` usage. But I was trying to utilize the es6 array destructing to return multiple values from a promise

Comment: @Abrar it seems you only need multiple values because you want access to the `app` argument. But with this change you don't need the multiple values.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the catch, I made the it callback `async` now.

Comment: Thanks @Kyefus. It worked! Just to clarify I was wrong assuming that `app.candidates()` does not return a promise. My bad

Comment: @Abrar did that `async satisfy` work I'm curious, I didn't know that would work.

Comment: Yes, the tests passed with `async satisfy`

Comment: Oh amazing thank you for sharing @Abrar and Kyefus!! @Abrar there is actually a bug in the `async satisfy` you need an `await` on each of those `expect`s. I edited the solution above.

Comment: That's weird. The tests actually passed without throwing any errors without using `async`. Any idea why that happened? @Noitidart

Comment: @Abrar the tests may pass, but would have asynchronously went ahead and then completed retroactively. With the `await`s now, the tests that come after will wait for the older to complete. OR `satisfy` does not support async tests. Can you try to make one of the expects inside `satisfy` fail and see if the fail happens before other tests that come after it? Also can provide `--bail` option in `mocha.opts` or CLI when running `mocha test` to make it abort testing after first error, lets see if it aborts after first error within `satisfy`.